# MongoDB, Javascript: Map an array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am building a projects with MongoDB and Javascript (Meteor,React) , I created a data structure like this:

```
messages: [
   {
      user: "IDofUser",
      text: "sometext",
   },
   {
      user: "IDofUser2",
      text: "someothertext"
   }
]
```

And what I cant figure is how to show these informations in my web page, because as you may already know you need to map once when you want to get "messages" so how can I map again inside objects inside that array.

Comment: Are you using Blaze, React or Angular? Is this data in your database? Have you written some layout code ? Please share that

Answer (score 0):

You mean array of objects? Assuming this is the array of object

```
      [
         {user : {
                 name:'blah
                 messages: [
                        user: "IDofUser",
                        text: "sometext",
                 ]
              }
         },
             {user : {
                 name:'blah2
                 messages: [
                        user: "IDofUser2",
                        text: "sometext2",
                 ]
              }
         },
      ]
```

and it is stored in a variable users :

the code would be:

```
      users.map((user)=> {
        user.messages.map((message)=>{
             // You can get the message Per USER here.
             // via message.text and message.user
        })
      })
```